# Make chart marker point overwrite x-axis line in winform chart c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, charts

I want my chart marker point overwriting x-axis line.

From this :

[image]

To this :

[image]

So it was like the marker point position is in front of x-axis line. However i can't find toFront() property in chart marker series.

Is it possible ? Im using .net basic chart.

Edit :
I've been successful overwriting the x-axis line with this code :

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
```

But the "majortickmark" still visible :

[image]

Comment: `AxisX.LineWidth = 0` should turn off the whole axis. To turn off other elements like tickmarks or gridlines set their Enabled property to false!

Comment: if i set majortickmark Enabled to false, it will disable the whole majortick in x-axis. I only want to disable majortick mark in marker point position not in all position.

Comment: Sorry, not possible.